# How to interrupt/block main thread if Hystrix timeouts

Tags: java, hystrix

I am using HystrixProperty in Java 8 for setting timeout on a method. I have written a fallback method where a lot of things are going on. Everything is working fine except that even after timeout, the main thread doesn't stop execution of the method. It surely calls the fallback method but doesn't interrupt/block the main method execution. Please see the example below.

Client calls Method1.

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod ="Method1Fallback", 
commandProperties = {
@HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "40000"),
@HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.strategy", value = "SEMAPHORE")},  commandKey = "HystrixExample")
Method1 () {
 //Line 1 -> Hystrix times out in these calls
 Some Lines of Code.. API Calls, etc.

 //Line 2 -> Rest of the code
 Some Lines of Code.. API-2 Calls, etc.  

}

Method1Fallback() {

Some lines of code.. API-3 Calls, etc. 
}
```

Now, the hystrix times out at the mentioned line 1 and calls the fallback method positively. But, it doesn't stop the execution of Method1 and goes on to call the rest of the code in Method1 ,i.e. calling API-2, etc.

1. I want to stop the Method1 execution as soon as it times out.
2. Due to this, I am not sure which result (from Method1 or Method1Fallback) is passed on to the client as response.

Comment: Are you sure the method has not been interrupted? It should have been, check for the interrupted status. Also make sure the relevant Hystrix property is set to true (the default): https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#execution.isolation.thread.interruptOnTimeout

Comment: @PetrJaneček, verified the interrupted status and is false.